# How are multiple arguments stored in a message in Switchyard

Tags: integration, jbossfuse

How are multiple arguments passed to a service in Switchyard stored in the message? For example, if I define a service contract as

```
public void service(String param1)
```

I know that param1 becomes the body of the message. What if the contract is defined as

```
public void service(String param1, String param2)
```

How are both arguments stored in the message, and how would I access each of them in a Camel route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switchyard project doesn't accept multi-arguments. 
Thus one would need to create a separate class and pass the attributes inside the object.

Keep a watch on this forum too - https://developer.jboss.org/message/909685

Thanks!